# 400 Bad request when generating the Google API access token using Go iamcredentials client API

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, access-token

I am trying to implement `iamcredentials` Go API client to generate an `Access Token` to access some Google APIs via REST API, I am using this code

```
    package main

    import (
        "context"
        "log"

        "google.golang.org/api/iamcredentials/v1"
    )

    func main() {
        iamcredentialsService, err := iamcredentials.NewService(context.Background())
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("error initialize iamcredential Service ", err)
            return
        }
        accessTokenCall := iamcredentialsService.Projects.ServiceAccounts.GenerateAccessToken(
            "projects/-/serviceAccounts/some-sa@some-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com:generateAccessToken",
            &iamcredentials.GenerateAccessTokenRequest{
                Scope: []string{
                    iamcredentials.CloudPlatformScope,
                },
            },
        )

        iamResp, err := accessTokenCall.Do()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("error generate access token", err)
            return
        }

        log.Println(iamResp)
    }
```

But when I tried to run the above snippet, I got this message

```
go run main.go 

error generate access token googleapi: Error 400: Request contains an invalid argument., badRequest
```

Is there any way to check which one is causing the above response? I am not sure since there isn't any good example of implementation. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Notes :

- I have checked following documentation on this topic https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials and this https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/iamcredentials/v1#pkg-overview
- I have already setup the Service account using `Service Account Token Creator` role on IAM and also enabled the IAM API from the console
- Also I have added `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the environment variables as suggested

Comment: `"projects/-/serviceAccounts/some-sa@some-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com:generateAccessToken",` are you sure you have the right info in there?

Comment: It seems i was mistakenly used the name based on HTTP Endpoint example :D, now the problem already solved using @guillaume-blaquiere 's solution, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DanielFarrell is right, you need to remove the `:generateAccessToken` at the end. Here the documentation in the code. Don't hesitate to explore it, it's open source ;)

```
// GenerateAccessToken: Generates an OAuth 2.0 access token for a
// service account.
//
// - name: The resource name of the service account for which the
//   credentials are requested, in the following format:
//   `projects/-/serviceAccounts/{ACCOUNT_EMAIL_OR_UNIQUEID}`. The `-`
//   wildcard character is required; replacing it with a project ID is
//   invalid.
func (r *ProjectsServiceAccountsService) GenerateAccessToken(name string, generateaccesstokenrequest *GenerateAccessTokenRequest) *ProjectsServiceAccountsGenerateAccessTokenCall {
    c := &ProjectsServiceAccountsGenerateAccessTokenCall{s: r.s, urlParams_: make(gensupport.URLParams)}
    c.name = name
    c.generateaccesstokenrequest = generateaccesstokenrequest
    return c
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, yes it was my mistake for misusing name param based on HTTP Endpoint example from rest api docs :) @guillaume-blaquiere